# Can not work converter WMF to SVG with Batik

Tags: svg, wmf

I have to convert WMF image to SVG image.

I used Batik and got this code but it is not worked. After running the code, a SVG image file is created but it is totally empty file. I have no idea why. Help me please.

```
public void converter(String a) throws IOException, TranscoderException
{
    String wmfPath="D:\\locales\\sample.wmf";
    FileOutputStream awmfPath=new FileOutputStream("D:upload\\a6.wmf");
    File wmf=new File(wmfPath);
    FileInputStream wmfStream=new FileInputStream(wmf);
    ByteArrayOutputStream imageOut=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[]buffer=new byte[1024*1024];
    int noOfByteRead=0;

    while((noOfByteRead = wmfStream.read()) != -1)
    {
            imageOut.write(noOfByteRead);
            awmfPath.write(noOfByteRead);
    }

    imageOut.flush();
    awmfPath.flush();

    WMFTranscoder transcoder = new WMFTranscoder();
    TranscodingHints hints=new TranscodingHints();
    hints.put(WMFTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT,2000f);
    hints.put(WMFTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH,2000f);
    transcoder.setTranscodingHints(hints);

    TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageOut.toByteArray()));
    ByteArrayOutputStream svg = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(svg);

    transcoder.transcode(input, output);
    String svgFile = StringUtils.replace(wmfPath,"wmf","svg");
    FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(svgFile);
    fileOut.write(svg.toByteArray());

    fileOut.flush();
}
```

Comment: Is the code giving no errors or warnings?  Have you chacked that `imageOut` does contain a copy of the WMF file?

Comment: POI uses Batik for the SVG output, but has a different WMF parser, maybe [try it for this picture](https://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ppt-wmf-emf-renderer.html). If it doesn't work, you can send me the file privately for fixing the WMF parser in this regards.

Comment: thank you, everyone. I tried already to use POI. It is very good and is running well in test. But POI version for Exel download Funtion is not matched in Project (POI for Exel is downlevel). Anyway, thangs for your advice